# How to stop data grid adding additional row?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm populating datagrid view like this.

```
var dataTable = new viewregisterdVotersOP().getTableRegVoters(lgdiv, elecid);
if (dataTable == null || dataTable.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    tempmsg1 = "Couldn't find data in the system";
    setErrorMSG(tempmsg1);
}
else
{
    dgvView.DataSource = new viewregisterdVotersOP().getTableRegVoters(lgdiv, elecid);
}
```

But it adds an extra empty row. How to stop that?

Comment: I don't know enough to put an answer, but this looks like it's because either you're appending to a table that already has a row or your table that you're inserting has a blank row at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it adds an extra empty row. How to stop that?

That row is there to allow users to add new rows to grid, you can disable that either in code behind or at design view using [DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)property

In code behind:

```
dgvView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

Or set the property to false in design view.